# What is updmendex.exe?

Tags: texlive-2020

My AV System (Sophos Home Premium) has quarantined this file with the description "Generic ML PUA" and stating that "it is not malicious but has potentially harmful behaviour".  What is the purpose of this application and is it safe to take it out of quarantine?

Answer (score 3):

The programs `mendex` and `upmendex` are extensions of `makeindex`, with `upmendex` an extension of `mendex`.

Their man pages are available in English, but the full documentation for `mendex` is only available in Japanese. A Google translation of the abstract says

> `mendex` is a command line tool for indexing documents. It sorts the index list file (`.idx`) extracted by LATEX and formats it into the actual index source file. Compatible with `makeindex`, Furthermore, it is specialized to reduce the trouble of handling "reading". The format of the output index is determined according to the style file. Also, by giving a dictionary file, the reading of the kanji in the index can be read. It will be registered. You can create up to 3 levels of index hierarchy.

(I didn't try to fix the grammar.)

The sources for `upmendex` (where the `u` should stand for Unicode) are [available on GitHub](https://github.com/t-tk/upmendex-package).

So I should be on the side that the program is safe and it's just a false positive. Maybe you can ask the developer to investigate on the issue.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful.